# Syntax Error in Function Return Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, syntax-error

I'm a python beginner and I'm trying to write this function:

```
def order(sentence):
    return '' if sentence==''
```

This function basically returns an empty string if the argument (which is called sentence) is an empty string.
I know I can simply do this instead:

```
def order(sentence):
    if sentence=='':
      return ''
```

Nevertheless, I am curious why the first example doesn't work. I can't really see what I wrote wrong.
I am using python 3.8 by the way.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Simple not valid Python syntax. Maybe you were thinking of Ruby.

Comment: Having the if statement by itself in the return statement is not valid syntax? Do i have to use the else?

Comment: You can use the second version of the code from your question: `if sentence=='': return ''`. Your first version, `return '' if sentence==''`, has no advantage over the second version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a conditional expression, you need an `else` as well. It will not work otherwise.

```py
def order(sentence):
    return '' if sentence=='' else None # or anything else
```

**Resources:**

- [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)

Comment: That's a conditional expression, not an if-statement.

Comment: @khelwood Oh, oops! Thanks

Comment: I guess this is the right answer. I really thought I could use the if by itself.

Comment: As khelwood said in his comment, you were probably thinking of Ruby or another programming language. But yes, it's not correct syntax.

Comment: The only programming language I know is python XD. I just instinctively thought that I can do this with python because I knew it worked with an if-else. Why not if only? Anyways thanks for the response

Comment: @Sleepy Quite simply put, the reason that there is no `return X if Y` construct in Python is that when Python was created, the people who created it didn't put a `return X if Y` construct in it. Programming language features don't exist until they are implemented, and nobody implemented that feature, so it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can try as following:

```
def order(sentence):
    return '' if sentence=='' else "x" # or something else
```

Comment: the thing is whats wrong with my return statement? Using if in a return statement without the else is in the syntax. Why am i getting this error?

Comment: What do you expect the function to return if you do not provide else?